# C++ template point to member

Tags: c++, templates, pointers, pointer-to-member

I have theoretical question about templates in C++. 
Let's say I have the following code:

[Code](http://gcc.godbolt.org/#%7B%22version%22:3,%22filterAsm%22%3a%7B%22labels%22%3atrue,%22directives%22%3atrue,%22commentOnly%22%3atrue%7D,%22compilers%22%3a%5B%7B%22source%22%3a%22struct%20C%7B%5Cn%20%20%20int%20val%20=%2015;%5Cn%7D;%5Cn%5Cnstruct%20B%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20C%20c;%5Cn%20%20%20%20int%20k%20=%209;%5Cn%7D;%5Cn%5Cnstruct%20A%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20template%3Ctypename%20T,%20typename%20FType,%20FType%20T%3a%3a%2a%20Field%20=%20nullptr%3E%5Cn%20%20%20%20void%20test%28T&%20d%29%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20%28Field%20!=%20nullptr%29%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20int%20a%20=%20d.%2aField;%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%5Cn%20%20%20%20%7D%5Cn%7D;%5Cn%5Cn%5Cnint%20main%28int%20argc,%20char%20%2aargv%5B%5D%29%5Cn%7B%5Cn%5Cn%20%20%20%20A%20a;%5Cn%20%20%20%20B%20be;%5Cn%20%20%20%20%5Cn%5Cta.test%3CB,%20int,%20&B%3a%3ac%3a%3aval%3E%28be%29;%5Cn%5Ct//a.test%3CB,%20int,%20&B%3a%3ak%3E%28be%29;%5Cn%7D%22,%22compiler%22%3a%22/usr/bin/g++-4.7%22,%22options%22%3a%22-O0%20-std=c++0x%22%7D%5D%7D)

```
struct C{
   int val = 15;
};

struct B{
    C c;
    int k = 9;
};

struct A{
    template<typename T, typename FType, FType T::* Field = nullptr>
    void test(T& d){
        if (Field != nullptr){
            int a = d.*Field;
        }
    }
};


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    A a;
    B be;

    a.test<B, int, &B::c::val>(be);
    //a.test<B, int, &B::k>(be);
}
```

The question is: why I can't access to **B::c::val** field, when I can access **B::k**? 
**B::c::val** is also member of **B**. Or not?

Comment: int val = 15; this wrong inside a structre...use constructors to have initial value.

Comment: There's no such thing as `B::c::val`. You can only have a class or namespace name to the left of `::`. `B::c` is neither. This has nothing to do with templates whatsoever.

Comment: this would work      "     a.test<C, int, &C::val>(be.c)"

Comment: Nice work give us the interactive compiler link for the code.

Comment: `B::c::val is also member of B` of course not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`B::c` is a member of `B`, and `C::val` is a member of `C`, but there is nothing like `B::c::val`

What you are wanting to do here could be achieved like this:

```
struct A {
  template<typename T, typename OType, typename IType, OType T::* OField = nullptr, IType OType::* IField = nullptr>
  void test(T& d){
    if (OField != nullptr && IField != nullptr) {
      auto a = d.*OField.*IField; 
    }
  }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    A a;
    B be;

    a.test<B, C, int, &B::c, &C::val>(be);
}
```

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f89b96274218e223

Of course, you could provide the member pointers as function parameters and let the compiler deduce the type parameters for you.